# How do you prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t - 1} \text{ dt}$ converges for $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 1$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The integral comes from the Mellin Transform representation of the Riemann zeta function, and is such that:

$$
\zeta{(z)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t - 1} \text{ dt}
$$

Since this is a nonelementary integral, you cant prove convergence by evaluating it with the fundamental theorem of calculus and taking a limit (I think, maybe with polylogarithms but I don't know much about those). I do know that the function can be split up into $\int_{0}^{1}$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty}$ to deal with the problematic region separately.

As far as bounding functions and a direct comparison test, I found that:

$e^t -1 \geq t $

And so,

$\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t - 1} \leq \frac{t^{z-1}}{t} = t^{z-2}$

For which the integral $\int_{0}^{1}t^{z-2} \text{ dt} $ converges for $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 1$ and therefore so does $\int_0^1 \frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t - 1} \text{ dt}$

I am not sure how to handle the other part of the integral though, what can I use to compare $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t - 1} \text{ dt}$ to in order to show that it converges? There might just be something really simple that I am missing.

Comment: For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a $t_0$ large enough such that $e^{t} - 1 \geq t^{n}$  for all $t > t_0$. In other words, $e^t$ grows faster than any polynomial power.

Answer (score 1):

As $t \to 0$, the integrand behaves as $t^{z -2} \implies  \Re\left(z - 2\right) > -1$.

Answer (score 1):

The complex number $z$ in the integrand is fixed, so we can ignore the factor $\Gamma(z)$. To prove the integral converges, it suffices to show it is absolutely convergent.  Since
$|t^{z-1}| = t^{a - 1}$ when $z = a+bi$, show
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{a-1}}{e^t-1}\,dt
$$
converges when $a > 1$. We might as well write $a-1$ as a single expression, say $c$, and show
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{c}}{e^t-1}\,dt
$$
converges when $c > 0$.  Note $e^t > 1$ for $t > 0$, so the integrand is positive on $(0,\infty)$.

The function $t^c/(e^t-1)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and near $t=0$ the integrand behaves like $t^c/t = t{c-1}$, which is integrable on $(0,1)$ since $\int_{\varepsilon}^1 t^{c-1}\,dt = (t^c/c)|_{\varepsilon}^1 = 1/c-\varepsilon^c/c \to 1/c$ as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$. We used $c>0$ in the last limit calculation.

Thus we can split the integral into two parts, say $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$.  There is no trouble on $[0,1]$ (because the integrand is a bounded continuous function there), and on $[1,\infty)$ we  have the lower bound $e^t - 1 > (1/2)e^t$, so
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{t^{c}}{e^t-1}\,dt < \int_1^\infty \frac{2t^{c}}{e^t}\,dt.
$$
Split up $e^t$ on the right into $e^{t/2}e^{t/2}$ so we can get $t^c/e^{t/2}$, which has a positive upper bound on $[1,\infty)$, say $t^c/e^{t/2} \leq B_c$. Then
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{2t^{c}}{e^t}\,dt \leq 2B_c\int_1^\infty e^{-t/2}\,dt < \infty.
$$

Comment: I don't quite understand that last two steps. How can you say that $ \int_1^\infty \frac{2t^{c}}{e^t}\,dt $ is any more obviously convergent than $\int_1^\infty \frac{t^{c}}{e^t-1}\,dt $ ? I mean they both clearly are, but how does the bounding function demonstrate that in a way that the first doesn't? And then the last step, how does $t^c/e^{t/2}$ have a self-evident upper bound where $\frac{2t^{c}}{e^t}$ does not?

Comment: Just keep reading. Did you not read until the end? I explain on the last few lines why the integral of $t^c/e^{t/2}$ over $[1,\infty)$ converges.

Comment: Sorry i accidentally hit enter before I finished typing, didn't expect and instant reply back

Comment: Well, today is your lucky day (or unlucky day, depending on how you look at it).

Answer (score 0):

The integral

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-1}\,dt\tag{1}$$

can be evaluated using the relationship

$$\frac{1}{e^t-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n t}.\tag{2}$$

which is valid for $t>0$.

---

Since

$$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-n t} t^{s-1}\,dt=\Gamma(s)\, n^{-s},\quad Re(s)>0$$

term-wise integration of formula (2) above leads to

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$$

which is only valid for $\Re(s)>1$.